# problem on Loading .h5 model with keras and tensorflow_hub

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\first_step\app.py", line 19, in 
model = load_model('model.h5')  # Load your trained deep learning model
File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\first_step\app.py", line 15, in load_model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path,
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 262, in load_model
return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\base_layer.py", line 870, in from_config
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'KerasLayer' using config={'name': 'keras_layer_1', 'trainable': False, 'dtype': 'float32', 'handle': 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_130_224/classification/4'}.

Exception encountered: Trying to load a model of incompatible/unknown type. 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\87c08e811d90a898c320e6626614764b3f4e562b' contains neither 'saved_model.pb' nor 'saved_model.pbtxt'.

solve the error loading .h5 file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.